# migrate database from one MVC project to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-migration

I am using Visual Studio 2013. Unfortunately I am facing some problems with my MVC project. So I created a new project and I need to fetch database to my new project but can't figure out how to fetch database. I am using data first approach, entity framework and IIS Express localhost.

**Update:**
I copied connection string from web.config of old project and pasted it over new project's connection string.(Note I first created ado.net entity data model in new project and then pasted string over its connection string).

Now in `server explorer` window > `data connections` my `Entities` connection has changed to `defaultconnection` and I get exception `The underlying provider failed on Open` on executing query of new projects database. But I am unable to fetch old database tables.

Comment: Do you need copy of old database instance too point out new prorject?

Comment: I copied old project's database connection string from web.config and pasted it over new database connection string.

Comment: I first created `ado.net entity data model` in new project and then replaced connection string by old database connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Your DBContext likely has the name of the database connection in one of it's constructors.

This corresponds to the `name` of a connection string the web.config.

So move that configuration to your new web config and make sure your new DbContext references the correct name.

Comment: Its not working. In my new project I created `ado.net entity data model` whose dbcontext name is `Entities`. Then I commented its connection string in web.config and pasted the connection string of my old project whose dbcontext name is also `Entities`. I refreshed my `data connections` in `server explorer` window. Noting happened!

Comment: yes. First `DefaultConnection` has 5 tables as I am using `Individual user authentication`.